# Hbase - does RegexStringComparator work with binary values?

Tags: java, hbase

We make use of `RegexStringComparator` but are not sure about filtering values written as bytes to hbase using a regular expression like `1|2|3`.

Can anybody confirm that this works? Documentation is not saying anything.

**EDIT**: I think my question was not clear enough. I am aware that I can use `RegexStringComparator` as Hbase filter with values written to Hbase as string such as:

**row key**: `myrow123`

**column**: `c:name, timestamp=1234567891234, value=Irene`

But can I also use it with values written to Hbase as bytes such as:

**row key**: `\x6d\x79\x72\x6f\x31\x32\x33`

**column**: `c:\x6e\x61\x6d\x65, timestamp=1234567891234, value=\x49\x72\x65\x6e\x65`

Answer (score 0):

It does work. We have used such regex in our projects. `RegexStringComparator` internally uses `Pattern.compile` followed by `matcher(str).find()` by default and anything that works using the Java regex API should work in HBase filters too.

Comment: Hi balaudt, thanks for your reply. I specified my question in the original post.

Comment: The only supported data type in HBase is byte[] and hence both the rows mentioned above are equivalent (Unless the second is explicitly saved using raw string to bytes). In fact, the client api expects byte[] for all: rowKey, columnFamily, columnQualifier and value. Shell just provides an easy way of putting and displaying primitives by conversion to/from byte[]. When we use RegexStringComparator, byte[] data is converted to String using the given encoding (defaulting to UTF8) and then regex API will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Is there solution for this other than writing custom Comparator?